# how to append the image the user has taken from ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync() to a FormData

Tags: react-native, expo, form-data, react-native-image-picker

I am trying to append the photo taken by the user from ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync()

I need to send the file itself not a base64 version of it and I am using expo with react native so react-native-fs doesn't work with me

I can get the path of the taken photo and the some other properties of it but not the image itself

A snippet of the code I am using to get the image is:

```
let permission = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    if (permission.granted === false) {
      alert("Camera access is required for single upload");
      return;
    }
    const takenImage = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();
    if (takenImage.cancelled === true) {
      alert("No images were taken");
      return;
    }

    let data = new FormData();
```

And the request is

```
await axios
      .post("A link here", data, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.response));
```

So any ideas how can i do this trick?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to append image to form data

```
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('Name of the key from backend', {
    uri: 'file path of image',
    type: 'image type e.g jpeg/png etc',
    name: 'image name',
    });
```

After that send request like this

```
let axiosConfig = {headers:{}}
axios.post(URL, formdata, axiosConfig)
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying. The backend code is designed to get a File in the FormData. Sending the path, type and the name return with response of 400 and a message from the server "There was an error parsing the body". So I need to send the file itsetlf in the form data not the path of it.